# Unlock content of file after certain period has passed?

Tags: linux, mac

I'm trying to give someone a certain information, and would like to be able to make them wait for the information to be available. Much like a Christmas present you’re not supposed to open before Christmas. The file would be a text file or a video.

I know of no app or service that let's you do that. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 2):

This is not really doabler as just a file as a file has no intrinsic knowledge of how old it is (that can't easily be fooled).

What you could do is set up a password protected file and automate the sending of a message with a password at a point in the future.  You could set this up yourself using a cronjob (or at) or use an online service. (A reminder service or dead man switch service could work). In fact, looking at it (and I've never used their service) http://www.deadman.io looks to allow you to send arbitrary files.

Comment: Thanks. Dead man's switch services look like something I could use for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `at`, for example:

```
sudo at April 1 <<'EOF'
echo 'Do you know what this is? /home/recipient_username/file' | write recipient_username
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/home/recipient_username/file bs=1M count=13
EOF
```